# MySQL INSERT failed

Tags: mysql, derby

my code is

```
connect 'jdbc:derby:sampleclient';
    set schema SYMMETRIC;
    insert into "sale_transaction" ("tran_id", "store", "workstation", "day", "seq") values (1000, '1', '3', '2007-11-01', 100);
    insert into "sale_return_line_item"("tran_id", "item_id"," price", "quantity") values (1000, 110000055, 0.65, 1); 
    select * from "sale_transaction";
    select * from "sale_return_line_item";
```

im trying to insert data into mysql from derby i.e im replicating data, but when i type in the command below im getting error shown below, and push-derby2mysql is the file which contains code

```
 C:\symmetric-ds-3.0.1-server\symmetric-ds-3.0.1\samples>sh ij.sh push-derby2my
    l.sql
    ij version 10.5
    ij> connect 'jdbc:derby:sampleclient';
    ij> set schema SYMMETRIC;
    0 rows inserted/updated/deleted
    ij> insert into "sale_transaction" ("tran_id", "store", "workstation", "day",
    eq") values (1000, '1', '3', '2007-11-01', 100);
    ERROR 42X51: The class 'org.jumpmind.symmetric.db.derby.DerbyFunctions' does n
     exist or is inaccessible. This can happen if the class is not public.
    ERROR XJ001: Java exception: 'org.jumpmind.symmetric.db.derby.DerbyFunctions:
    va.lang.ClassNotFoundException'.
    ij> insert into "sale_return_line_item"("tran_id", "item_id"," price", "quanti
    ") values (1000, 110000055, 0.65, 1);
    ERROR 42X14: ' price' is not a column in table or VTI 'SYMMETRIC.sale_return_l
    e_item'.
    ij> select * from "sale_transaction";
    tran_id    |store|wo&|day       |seq
    --------------------------------------------

    0 rows selected
    ij> select * from "sale_return_line_item";
    tran_id    |item_id    |price       |quantity   |returned_q&
    ------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Would you format the question to make code easier to read? And give an appropriate title...

Comment: 1) You should title your question something relevant to your problem. 2) What are you trying to do? What have you tried? I don't see a question here other then "error please help".

Answer (score 1):

If you read the error..

> The class 'org.jumpmind.symmetric.db.derby.DerbyFunctions' does n exist or is inaccessible.

That is preventing any insert to happen so your posterior select does not get anything.

As error suggests, check:

1. If reference to **org.jumpmind.symmetric.db.derby.DerbyFunctions** is existing
2. If file for **org.jumpmind.symmetric.db.derby.DerbyFunctions** exists (probably here is the problem)
3. If class is public (Probably yes)

**It looks like you don't have SymmetricDS package installed**. You can download it from [here](http://symmetricds.org/download).

Comment: That is exactly the point. You don't have the file therefore your code fails. You need to install org.jumpmind.symmmetric package. Try looking [here](http://symmetricds.org/download). I have edited answer to add link.